# Access a table on BigQuery using the API on APP Scritps

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-bigquery, google-oauth

I am trying to execute the following function. However, I get an error:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to bigquery.jobs.query failed with error: VPC Service Controls: Request is prohibited by organization's policy. vpcServiceControlsUniqueIdentifier: 09RldtnW9WG7f6KXB0Mnq6Sdp9a9PNeHnH5do8kyQJWFebex6fz65w.

I have access to project, and it not exists anything prohibited.

Do I need to insert an authtoken. How do I do that?

```
function runQuery() {
  // Replace this value with the project ID listed in the Google
  // Cloud Platform project.
  var projectId = 'vf-grp-ngbi-prd-svcs-01';

  var request = {
    useQueryCache: false,
    allowLargeResults: true,
    useLegacySql: false,
    query: " SELECT DISTINCT  ct.cust_type_loc_1_lvl_1_name FROM   `vf-pt-datahub.vfpt_dh_lake_edw_integrated_s.d_customer_type` ct WHERE end_dttm is not null"
  };
  var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId)
  
  return queryResults;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That error is consistent with your organization admins having established additional controls blocking this interaction.  See https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls for more information about VPC service controls.

Likely the next step is to follow up with your own admins to understand more.